# MathJax not properly rendered on Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, fonts, latex

As you know, some sites associated to Stack Exchange require MathJax to display equations in a Latex-type format. However, this is how [this link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=Gamma) looks in my computer:

> [image: https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=Gamma as rendered in my computer]

I installed Ubuntu a few days ago with the minimal setup so I guess I'll have to install a few more drivers/packages(?). Also, I'm not sure if it helps but my PC has an Nvidia graphic card and it's dual booted with Windows 10.

Do you know what packages should I `sudo apt-get install`?

Comment: Check your browser extensions.

Comment: I don't think that's a problem - those are snippets of the search results and not always full MathJax (e.g. random bolding in the middle), so they're not rendered as such.

Comment: Oh. Hmmm, yeah, actually, you're right muru. I've checked it on Windows and it looks the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL;DR

This is "expected" behaviour for a *search*. For some reason, the formatting breaks when **searching** causes bold highlighting.

---

As a comparison with another OS, MathJax is rendered correctly, on the [front page of SE.Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions), on OS X 10.13.6, using Chrome 88.0.4324.192:

> [image: MathJax displayed correctly]

However, when you search for a particular term then the MathJax formatting breaks. That is to say when using a link, with a search term included, *which causes that search term to be **bolded***, i.e. [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=mathjax), then the formatting is broken:

> [image: Broken MathJax in a search]

Comment: So many years using these sites and I haven't noticed it. Well, I guess you can always learn something new every day :), thanks.